# Keep Bootstrap 3 Dropdown open when has class active

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all Hi and Thanks.
*"Second, I need bootstrap 3 dropdown menu remains open when dropdown has class active."*
If someone have problem with this below is solution thanks to @Luceos

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#>2</a></li>
<li class="dropdown active"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">3<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="#">3-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3-2</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">3-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">6</a></li>
```

*"Active class is add via php, but how to achieve that dropdown is opened when active class is in link 3 or 3 and 3-1, 3 and 3-2,3 and 3-3 when page is loaded?"*
If dropdown class is active when page is loaded dropdown is open and is prevent from being closed.

Solution:

```
$(function(){
$(".dropdown.active").toggleClass("open",true);
$(".dropdown.active").on("hide.bs.dropdown",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) specification, you can add the class `open` to the list item to have it open on browser load..

```
// listen for browser/jquery ready
$(function()
{
    $(".dropdown.active").toggleClass("open",true);
});
```

I see you also want to prevent it from being closed?

```
$(function()
{
    $(".dropdown.active").on("hide.bs.dropdown",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach but with the same result (only prevent works fine). I modified your solution by removing the dot from open class and now works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, sorry sometimes errors get in even if you try so hard not to get any. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Im having some difficulty getting this working at the following URL: http://www.shandakenprojects.org/ Any idea what might be going wrong?